# Reading back generated vertices and fragment OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Is there any way to read back from server space vertices and fragments generated from vertex and fragment shaders back to client space?

Is there specific functions to do this or some method by which this is done?

And if so what is the function call or method to do this?

Comment: What is "server space?

Comment: ...like [transform feedback](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transform_Feedback)?

Comment: @NicolBolas Memory owned by the server, presumably.

Comment: server space was referring to what gets uploaded to the OpenGL server memory

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can read the vertex shader output with [transform feedback](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transform_Feedback).

You can read the fragment shader output with [`glReadPixels()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glReadPixels.xhtml).

Comment: what about for textures? is there some texture functions that can do this? specifically to which point was a texel applied?

Comment: What do you mean by texture functions?

Comment: If you're asking whether you can read from textures, well, yes you can.  That is the whole point of textures.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289616/interpolated-texture-coordinates

i was reading this and he mentioned that he retrieved the coordinates with glGetTexImage()..... and i was wondering what exactly he did, but i cant comment there because i dont have 50 reputation